# Web scraping with Beautiful soup multiple tags

Tags: python, web

I'm trying to get multiple addresses from a web page with an A to Z of links.

First I get A to Z links with:

```
URL = "http://www.example.com"
html = urlopen(URL).read() 
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
content = soup.find("div", "view-content")
links = [BASE_URL + li.a["href"] for li in content.findAll("li")]
```

This works great and in links above I have a list of links to each individual web page with multiple addresses on each separate page.

For getting the addresses I need I used:

```
for item in links[0:5]:
    try:
        htmlss = urlopen(item).read()
        soup = bfs(htmlss, "lxml")
        titl = soup.find('div','views-field-title').a.contents
        add = soup.find('div','views-field-address').span.contents
        zipp = soup.find('div','views-field-city-state-zip').span.contents
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

The above code will take each link and get the first address on the page with all the A's and the first address on the page with all the B's and so on.

My problem is that on some of the pages there are multiple addresses on each page and the above code only retrieves the first address on that page i.e. First A address first B address and so on.

I've tried using soup.findAll but it doesn't work with a.content or span.content

Basically I need to find the address lines in the html pages with non-unique tags. If I use soup.findAll I get all the content for say (div, views-field-title) which gives me a lot of content I don't need.

Example of some html:

```
<div class="views-field-nothing-1"></div>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
    <span class="field-content">
        <div class="views-field-title">
            <span class="field-content">
                <a href="/golf-courses/details/ca/alameda/chuck-corica-golf-complex-earl-fry">

                    Chuck Corica Golf Complex, Earl Fry

                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="views-field-address">
            <span class="field-content"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="views-field-city-state-zip">
            <span class="field-content">

                Alameda, California 94502-6502

            </span>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="views-field-value"></div>
```

```
<div class="views-field-nothing-1"></div>
<div class="views-field-nothing">
    <span class="field-content">
        <div class="views-field-title">
            <span class="field-content">
                <a href="/golf-courses/details/ca/alameda/chuck-corica-golf-complex-jack-clark">

                    Chuck Corica Golf Complex, Jack Clark

                </a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="views-field-address">
            <span class="field-content">

                1 Clubhouse Memorial Rd

                <br></br>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="views-field-city-state-zip">
            <span class="field-content">

                Alameda, California 94502-6502

            </span>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

This is just a sample of similar html I need to find data for. Thanks

Comment: Can you give us some sample HTML? And `.find()` returns just the one element while `.find_all()` gives you a list. For a list you'll need to process each element.

Comment: Did you look at using [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead? They can simplify queries like these; `links = soup.select('div.view-content li a[href]')` to get all links with an `href` attribute in `li` elements in `div`s with the class `view-content`, to give you an example.

Comment: Apologies for late reply and thanks for your answers Martijn./

Comment: Apologies for late reply & thanks for your answers Martijn. Some html: <div class="views-field-title">
    <span class="field-content">
        <a href="/golf-courses/details/ca/alameda/chuck-corica-golf-complex-earl-fry">
            Chuck Corica Golf Complex, Earl Fry
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="views-field-address">
    <span class="field-content">
        1 Clubhouse Memorial Rd
        <br></br>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="views-field-city-state-zip">
<span class="field-content">
    Alameda, California 94502-6502
Its the addresses needed. Thanks for the help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add that detail. Make sure to use a code block for HTML (indenting all lines with 4 spaces).